# Rect element can not be filled using css in Firefox

Tags: firefox, d3.js, svg

I'm currently stucked in this 'simple' problem using Mozilla Firefox (any version): I want to fill a rect element by using standard CSS. I've prepared a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3ptuhna/1/) which shows the issue (compare Chrome and Firefox).

It even doesn't work for me using the standard 'fill' attribute of the rect element by using d3 and this line `.attr('fill', 'red');`.

I hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: rect elements can be filles using CSS so there must be some other problem. Unfortunately I'm blocked from accessing fiddles so you'll need to put the testcase in the question itself.

Comment: Don't use CSS to set width/height.

Comment: The "duplicate" question states, that fill should work using CSS.

Comment: Again, the problem is the width/height.

Comment: Ah, this means, it is filling the rect, but it is not visible because the rect's width and height are 0?

Comment: @noChance Exactly. Just use D3 to set the width/height: https://jsfiddle.net/zodsgobd/. I rolled back your edit since this **is** a duplicate.